# Getting error 'char16_t and char32_t undeclared'

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, std

I am developing a program in C++ on Linux. The gcc version is 4.5.1 20100924. I want to use std::atomic_int in my program. I have included atomic header as below:

```
include <atomic>
```

When I compile the program I get below errors:

```
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/atomic_base.h:87:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/atomic:41,
                 from ../Source/Main.h:33:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/atomicfwd_cxx.h:107:25: error: ‘char16_t’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/atomicfwd_cxx.h:107:33: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/atomicfwd_cxx.h:107:53: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/atomicfwd_cxx.h:110:25: error: ‘char32_t’ was not declared in this scope
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/atomicfwd_cxx.h:110:33: error: template argument 1 is invalid
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/bits/atomicfwd_cxx.h:110:53: error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

If I include `<cstdint>`, I get the same errors. The headers uchar.h and cuchar.h are not there on my system. How can I resolve the compilation errors?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you passing the option `-std=c++0x`?

Comment: `cuchar.h` is not a header, just `cuchar`. Anyways, `charXX_t` are "builtin" types, no include is not needed.

Comment: Passing -std=c++0x to g++ solved the problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I also suggest to upgrade the compiler; current version of GCC is 4.7, and 4.6 appeared in march 2011; since you want C++2011 features it is better to upgrade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDITED:**

I was wrong about that. just pass `--std=c++0x` to g++, and that would do it.

Comment: @LokiAstari Yep that's true dude. And my apologies.

Comment: @Loki: As far as I see it, the standard defines them as keywords, no need for an extra include. `cuchar` does not define types/aliases.

Comment: @geekowl: Almost a rant: This answer gives a fish after at first giving just some rotten fish. The other answer gives fish and some info about how to fish. Yet, the other wasn't accepted.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to delete your answer when you realize you were wrong and someone else was right?

Comment: I think chappjc is right. Completely changing ones answer to the tune of an existing answer is not good manner :P

Answer (score 8):

You seem to not have enabled C++11 support in your compiler or you use a compiler that has these new types not declared.

For `char16_t` and `char32_t`, you need no extra include.

---

g++ howto:

Type `g++ --version`. If it is at least 4.4, then it has support for [new string literals](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html). If not: You need a newer compiler version.

Then, make sure to pass `--std=c++0x` or `--std=c++11` to the compiler.